# Beautiful Soup - get text from all <li> elements in <ul>

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, splinter

With this code:

```
match_url = f'https://interativos.globoesporte.globo.com/cartola-fc/mais-escalados/mais-escalados-do-cartola-fc'

browser.visit(match_url)
browser.find_by_tag('li[class="historico-rodadas__rodada historico-rodadas__rodada--ativa"]').click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.html, 'html.parser')
innerContent = soup.findAll('ul',class_="field__players")

print (innerContent)
```

I've managed to fetch the `<ul>`:

```
[<ul class="field__players"><li class="player"...]
```

[image]

Now how can I access text for `player__name` and `player__value` for all players in the list?

Comment: First you innercontent.find_all('li'). Loop it and .find("p", {"class": "player_name"}) and so forth.

Comment: @8-Bit-Borges did my solution work for you?

Comment: @Sushil not yet. I get only the text for the first player

Comment: @8-BitBorges I have updated my solution. Check whether it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help u:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://interativos.globoesporte.globo.com/cartola-fc/mais-escalados/mais-escalados-do-cartola-fc')

src = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'html5lib')

innerContent = soup.find('ul',class_="field__players")

li_items = innerContent.find_all('li')

for li in li_items:
    p_tags = li.find_all('p')[:-1] #The [:-1] removes the last p tag from the list, which is player__label

    for p in p_tags:
        print(p.text)
```

Output:

```
Keno
2.868.755
Pedro
2.483.069
Bruno Henrique
1.686.894
Hugo Souza
809.186
Guilherme Arana
1.314.769
Filipe Luís
776.147
Thiago Galhardo
2.696.853
Vinícius
1.405.012
Nenê
1.369.209
Jorge Sampaoli
1.255.731
Réver
1.505.522
Víctor Cuesta
1.220.451
```

Comment: what is `ul`? `innerContent`?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant by ul.

Comment: for either method I get the error: `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'li'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: For which line?

Comment: and if I do `p_tags = innerContent[0].li.find_all('p')[:-1]`, with index [0], I get the fisrt player text, but not from the whole list of players

Comment: I found out the error. Will update it in my solution.

Comment: Check out my edit for the first code. I will do the same for the second code. But this should work.

Comment: I've updated the question with the target url, so you can test online

Comment: I get `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.6 x86_64)`, but I will accept you answer for your great help and effort

Comment: It is because your chromedriver version isn't correct. It worked fine for me because my chromedriver version was correct. No worries. Download chromedriver from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: thanks! and should I get version between 70 and 73?

Comment: Yes. Pls try it out and let me know whether it works.

Comment: I was using splinter, with geckodriver actually, with `browser = Browser("firefox", **executable_path, headless=False)`

Comment: Oh...Then u can continue using it. I did not have splinter (and I do not know what it is), so I used selenium. The main objective of the first few lines is to get the html code of the website. If u can do it with splinter, then it is well and good.

Answer (score 0):

I should just put this here to show you what he wants.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.html, 'html.parser')
innerContent = soup.findAll('ul',class_="field__players")
for li in innerContent.findAll('li'):
  player_name = li.find('p', class_ = "player__name")
  player_value = li.find('p', class_ = "player__value")
  print(player_name.text)
  print(player_value.text)
```